error when using intertext in aligned environment
In a quick demonstration, I would like to add additional text using the \intertext command.
I don't understand why I get an error: Package amsmath Error: Invalid use of \intertext.
I checked the docs but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}\label{eq:ka_coef_dissociation}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha &= \frac{\ce{[A^-]}}{C_0} \\
\ce{[A^-]} &=\alpha \cdot C_0 \\
\ce{[HA] + [A^-]} &= C_0 &\text{conservation de la matière}\\
\ce{[HA]} &=C_0 -\ce{[A^-]} = C_0 (1-\alpha)\\
\intertext{on peut montrer (par un tableau d'avancement par exemple) que  $a$}
K_a &=\frac{\ce{[H3O^+][A^-]}}{\ch{[HA]}} \\
    &=\frac{\alpha^2 \cdot {C_0}^2}{C_0 (1-\alpha)}\\
    &=C_0 \frac{\alpha^2}{1-\alpha} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


\intertext can only be used in an outer level display such as align. not as here in an aligned which is a box like a matrix or array rather than a full width display.

thanks for your return. In this case, how can I align my equations but only number all my equations once?

@Nicolas see egreg's answer in the linked post

as I specified, the error that appears does not appear in my original document but I understand that this could complicate my request. With the update I still get the hbox warning
